How to solve this Sturm-Liouville problem? Is there a general approach?
After using method of separation of variables on a PDE, I obtained two SL equations:
$$\tag{1} f(x)'' + f(x)\lambda = 0; f(x=0) = f(x=1) = 0$$
solution would simply be the eigenfunction f(x) = $\Big(\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\Big),\lambda = \Big(\frac{n\pi}{1}\Big)^2$
$$\tag{2} \frac{d}{dy}\bigg(\cos(y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}\bigg) - \lambda\sec(y)g(y) = 0; f(y=0) = 0, f(y=1) = f(x)$$
The second one, I haven't the slightest clue how to solve. Outside of S-L problems in the form of (1), I have little experience solving. I plugged this problem into a CAS like Matlab and it did yield a solution; So, (2) is solvable, I just have no idea how to arrive said solution. Is there a general method or technique for solving more complicated S-L problems like this one or any rules to follow, or is it primarily guesswork at substitutions to make it work (for example, subbing $\cos(y) = 1 - y^2/2$ for $y \approx 0$ might work for a specific S-L problem but not work here) as I've seen in some other more rigorous examples of S-L problems? Maybe there are some resources which lay out the process for more complicated S-L problems in no uncertain terms?

Note: The solution obtained in Matlab was the sum of 2 exponentials with opposite signs in their respective exponents i.e. it had the form $g(y) = e^{ry}-e^{-ry}$, so I'm guessing it used the characteristic form was used, though I don't see how it could be.

I would multiply the differential equation for $g(y)$ by $\cos (y)$ and then make the change of variables $ \frac{d}{du}= \cos y \frac {d}{dy}$ to obtain the equation $g_{uu}-\lambda g=0$ which has constant coefficients.

@MathFont That would work. Additionally, going back to it's original form (I factored our $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$ originally) would give $$\cos(y)^2 \frac{d^2 g(y)}{dy^2}-\sin(y)\cos(y)\frac{dg}{dy}-\lambda g(y) = 0$$ and using $$\frac{d}{du} = \cos y \frac{d}{dy}$$ and taking the derivative of that would yield $$\frac{d}{du}\Big(\frac{d}{du}\Big) = \cos y \frac{d}{dy}\Big(\cos y \frac{d}{dy}\Big) = \cos(y)^2 \frac{d^2}{dy^2}- \cos(y)\sin(y) \frac{d}{dy}$$ which matches the differential operator in the original form, so it would again go to $g_uu -\lambda g = 0$

@MathFont I think this also helped me to realize that generally speaking we're supposed to try and make clever substitutions to put it into an equation with constant coefficients and putting it into the form $$\Big(f(y)g(y)'\Big)' \pm \lambda g(y) = 0$$ (or something close to that for our Sturm-Liouville equation) just makes it easier to spot the substitutions like the one you used. $$\cos(y) \frac{d}{dy}\Big(\cos(y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}\Big) -\lambda g(y) = \frac{d}{du}\Big(\frac{d g}{du}\Big) - \lambda g(y) = \frac{d^2 g}{dy^2} - \lambda g$$. Much simpler substitution this way. Thanks!

@MathFont This might turn into another problem of its own as I don't know how $g(y)$ changes or how it changes the resulting characteristic equation. Does it just change to $g(u)$ and therefore the solution becomes $c_1 e^{r_1 u} + c_2 e^{r_2 u}$? If that's true, we would need an equation for $u$ as well
